# conditional probability - conditioned on set vs. conditioned on sigma algebra

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Assume $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F})_{n}, \mathbb{P})$ a filtrated probability space and $\tau$ a stopping time such that there is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \tau \le n+1  \; | \; \mathcal{F_{n}} \right] \ge \epsilon \;
$$

almost sure. Is it right to follow that

$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \tau \le n+1 \; | \; \tau > n \right] \ge \epsilon
$$
holds? My thoughts so far: As $\{\tau > n\} = \complement \{ \tau \le n\} $ and as $\tau$ is a stopping time, i.e.

$$\{\tau \le n \} \in \mathcal{F_{n}} $$

for all $n$, also $\{\tau > n\} \in \mathcal{F_{n}}$. Further I know that

$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \tau \le n+1  \; | \; \mathcal{F_{n}} \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{1}_{\{ \tau \le n+1 \}} \; | \; \mathcal{F_{n}}\right]
$$

and that

$$
\mathbb{P} \left[ \tau \le n+1 \; | \; \tau > n \right]  = \frac{\mathbb{P} \left[ \{ \tau \le n+1\} \cap  \{ \tau > n \} \right] }
{\mathbb{P} \left[  \tau > n  \right] } 
= \frac{\mathbb{P} \left[ \tau = n+1 \right] }
{\mathbb{P} \left[  \tau > n  \right] } .
$$

I am already sorry in advance if this is trivial - either trivially right or trivially wrong...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf 1}$First of all no need to say sorry. 
I don't understand what your plan was.

You are given:
\begin{align}
\E[\1_{\{\tau\leq n+1 \}} |\F_n]\geq \varepsilon
\end{align}
Let $A:=\{\tau >n \}$. On one hand:
\begin{align}
\E[\E[\1_{\tau\leq n+1}|\F_n]\ |\ \sigma(A)] \geq \E[\varepsilon|\sigma(A)] = \varepsilon
\end{align}
Since  $\sigma(A)\subset \F_n$, we have on the other hand:
\begin{align}
\E[\E[\1_{\tau\leq n+1}|\F_n]\ |\ \sigma(A)]=\E[\1_{\tau\leq n+1}|\sigma(A)]
\end{align}
by the  "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra wins" property. That means:
\begin{align}
\E[\1_{\tau\leq n+1}|\sigma(A)]\geq \varepsilon
\end{align}
And now we can conclude that:
\begin{align}
\P(\tau\leq n+1 | \tau > n)\geq \varepsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed respone...To be honest I just was not aware of
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\tau\leq n+1} \; | \;\sigma(\{\tau >n \})] = \mathbb{P}(\tau\leq n+1 \; | \; \tau > n)
$$
and still dont fully understand...I can see that this seems to make sense but how can I deduce formally?...

Comment: @u49K3df2 For every events $A$ and $B$ with $P(B)(1-P(B))\ne0$, $$E(\mathbf 1_A\mid\sigma(B))=P(A\mid\sigma(B))=P(A\mid B)\mathbf 1_B+P(A\mid B^c)\mathbf 1_{B^c}$$ (Note: After a while, rather than staying in the dark and basically trying to *guess* the results, it is preferrable to learn the true definitions...)

Comment: @u49K3df2 Indeed what Did said. You can deduce that formally by noting that  $\E[\cdot |\sigma(\{t>n\})]$ is a $\sigma(\{t>n\})$-measurable random variable which is constant on the atoms of $\sigma(\{t>n\})$.